# how to get the coordinates when we perform ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android

I want to perform some touch operations in my app.
When I touch on the screen and perform any move actions, I want to get the coordinates.
i.e the starting point x & y coordinate and the ending point x & y coordinate.
How can I perform it in onTouch()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it.

```
Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            coordinate.setStartX(event.getX());
            Log.i("start X" , String.valueOf(event.getX()));
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            coordinate.setEndX(event.getX());
            Log.i("end X" , String.valueOf(event.getX()));
            break;
        }           
    }
    return true;
}

private class Coordinate {

    private float startX;
    private float endX;

    /**
     * @return the startX
     */
    public float getStartX() {
        return startX;
    }
    /**
     * @param startX the startX to set
     */
    public void setStartX(float startX) {
        this.startX = startX;
    }
    /**
     * @return the endX
     */
    public float getEndX() {
        return endX;
    }
    /**
     * @param endX the endX to set
     */
    public void setEndX(float endX) {
        this.endX = endX;
    }       
}
```